# Equivalent to Solution Folders in VS Code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio, one can create "Solution Folders" to group different .NET projects into a virtual folder. Is there any equivalent solution for VS Code?

I've tried installing the extension [vscode-solution-explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fernandoescolar.vscode-solution-explorer), but it doesn't support virtual folders.

Comment: Just open a folder. It'll be the solution folder. It's just not virtual, but physical.

Comment: @Magnetron Thanks for suggesting, but I know how to create physical folders. I would like to know if it is possible to create virtual folders like in Visual Studio. PS: solution folders are not the root folder, fwiw

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need to create a virtual one?

Comment: @Magnetron for the same reason people create virtual folders in Visual Studio: you can improve the organization of your projects without worrying about fixing the dependencies paths. I can move one project to another place without problems and in my git repository all of them will be placed in the root. I have a .NET solution with ~50 projects, so this is important to me.

Comment: the extension that you mentioned seems to work. I loaded an existing solution, right click> create new folder. A virtual folder was created. Then I added an existing projet to solution (that was in a nother folder) and moved it to the virtual folder. Isn't that the behaviour you were expecting?

Comment: @Magnetron yes, exactly! Thank you! I don't know why I thought it didn't work when I tried. Probably created a virtual folder using a name of an existing physical folder

Comment: @Magnetron thanks. If you convert your comment into an answer, I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension that you mentioned seems to work.

Load an existing solution, right click in the solution file > "create new folder" . A virtual folder will be created. Then, add an existing project to solution and move it to the virtual folder.

Answer (score 8):

The extension [`vscode-solution-explorer`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fernandoescolar.vscode-solution-explorer) supports virtual folder. Here are the steps:

1. Search and install (extension id):

   ```
   fernandoescolar.vscode-solution-explorer
   ```
2. Looking in sidebar for last icon named "Solution":

   [image: Solution Explorer VS Code]
3. Click right button in file `.sln` and choice **Create folder**:

   [image: Create Folder = New Solution Folder in Visual Studio]
4. Choice name and press **enter**:

   [image: Name Solution Folder]
5. Drag yours projects for solution folder.